# Compile for Flash 10.1 in Flash Professional CS6

Tags: flash, adobe, samsung-smart-tv, flash-10

I'm currently working on a project for a Samsung Smart TV.

This project will require Flash, and the specifications state to compile for Flash 10.1 if I want to use it on the TV.  However, I'm looking at the publishing options in Flash Professional CS6, and I'm only given the option for 10.3, instead of 10, 10.1, or whatever other subversions of Flash 10. (I'm given the options for Flash 9, 8, 11, and more, though).

Is there any way to force CS6 to compile for Flash 10.1?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let me preface this by stating I don't have CS6; however, I assume it'd be the same as overlaying a player in previous versions.

1. You'll need to download the 10.1 playerglobal.swc, which is available from [Adobe's Archived Flash Player versions site.](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)
2. Place the playerglobal.swc in a FP10.1 folder in Flash Pro CS6 install path at /Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.1/playerglobal.swc

   Example: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.1
3. Create a publish target XML to add the Flash Player 10.1 option in Flash Pro's Publish settings dialog drop down.  These are found in /Common/Configuration/Players/

   Example: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/Players/FlashPlayer10_1.xml

   Copy and paste an existing Flash Player 10 XML as a template; or, it should be something like:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <players>
       <player id="FlashPlayer10" version="10" asversion="3">
           <name>Flash Player 10 & 10.1</name>
           <path builtin="true" />
           <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
           <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
           <playerDefinitionPath
               as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7"
               as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP10/playerglobal.swc" />
           <feature name="multiScreenPublish" supported="true" />
           <feature name="mobileAuthoringIntegration" supported="true" />
           <feature name="deviceSound" supported="false" />
           <feature name="exportStreamingSound" supported="true" />
           <feature name="exportEventSound" supported="true" />
           <feature name="FSCommand2" supported="false" />
           <feature name="gradient_linearRGB" supported="true" />
           <feature name="gradient_overflow" supported="true" />
           <feature name="shape_strokeHint" supported="true" />
           <feature name="shape_cap" supported="true" />
           <feature name="shape_join" supported="true" />
           <feature name="shape_mitre" supported="true" />
           <feature name="shape_scale" supported="true" />
           <feature name="linkage_exportForActionscript" supported="true" />
           <feature name="linkage_exportForRuntimeSharing" supported="true" />
           <feature name="linkage_exportInFirstFrame" supported="true" />
           <feature name="linkage_importForRuntimeSharing" supported="true" />
           <feature name="linkage_importAndAddToCache" supported="false" />
           <feature name="publish_localPlaybackSecurity" supported="true" />
           <feature name="publish_hardwareAcceleration" supported="true" />
           <feature name="symbol_blendMode" supported="true" />
           <feature name="actionScript_documentClass" supported="true" />
           <feature name="symbol_blendMode" supported="true" />
           <feature name="filters" supported="true" />
           <feature name="component_binding" supported="true" />
           <feature name="component_schema" supported="true" />
           <feature name="screens" supported="true" />
           <feature name="video" supported="true" />
           <feature name="deviceVideo" supported="false" />
           <feature name="accessibility" supported="true" />
           <feature name="dynamic_text_kerning" supported="true" />
           <feature name="static_text_charwidth_nondeviceFont" supported="true" />
           <feature name="static_text_charwidth_deviceFont" supported="true" />
           <feature name="advanced_anti_alias_text" supported="true" />
           <feature name="nine_slice_scaling" supported="true" />
           <feature name="runtimeNumberMinMax" supported="true" />
           <feature name="use8kSampleRate" supported="true" />
           <feature name="useDefineFont4ForDeviceText" supported="true" />
           <feature name="useDefineFont4ForEmbeddedFonts" supported="true" />
           <feature name="textLayoutFramework" supported="true" />
           <encodingPresets>
               <preset uuid="da5cac1a-417a-4d86-b7f7-ef21010a5d7d" name="FLV - Match Source Attributes (High Quality)"
                   ext="flv" default="true" />
           </encodingPresets>

           <testmenu>
               <menu name="ID_testInFlash" default="true" />
               <menu name="ID_testInDeviceCentral" />
           </testmenu>

           <debugmenu>
               <menu name="ID_debugtInFlash" default="true" />
               <menu name="ID_debugInDeviceCentral" />
           </debugmenu>

       </player>
   </players>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this when I get the chance!

Comment: @Jason Sturges - people have been proposing changes to your answer, could you take a quick look and decide if you are still happy with the original form of it?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Indicating this solution continues to work in Creative Cloud would be nice as a comment; otherwise, no need to add .app extensions.  Thanks.

Comment: Just for my future self, the PC equivalent for where to put the swc file is: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC 2015\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP10.1

Answer (score 4):

Jason's answer above is perfect - only one small change - make sure the line

```
as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP10/playerglobal.swc"
```

matches the path to where you have installed the playerglobal.swc - ie FP10.1 in Jason's example, not FP10

Answer (score 3):

for AdobeFlash CC xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<players>
    <player id="FlashPlayer10" version="10" asversion="3">
        <name>Flash Player 10.1</name>
        <path builtin="true" />
        <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
        <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
        <playerDefinitionPath
            as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7"
            as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.1/playerglobal.swc" />
        <feature name="multiScreenPublish" supported="true" />
        <feature name="mobileAuthoringIntegration" supported="true" />
        <feature name="deviceSound" supported="false" />
        <feature name="exportStreamingSound" supported="true" />
        <feature name="exportEventSound" supported="true" />
        <feature name="FSCommand2" supported="false" />
        <feature name="gradient_linearRGB" supported="true" />
        <feature name="gradient_overflow" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_strokeHint" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_cap" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_join" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_mitre" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_scale" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_exportForActionscript" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_exportForRuntimeSharing" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_exportInFirstFrame" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_importForRuntimeSharing" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_importAndAddToCache" supported="false" />
        <feature name="publish_localPlaybackSecurity" supported="true" />
        <feature name="publish_hardwareAcceleration" supported="true" />
        <feature name="symbol_blendMode" supported="true" />
        <feature name="actionScript_documentClass" supported="true" />
        <feature name="symbol_blendMode" supported="true" />
        <feature name="filters" supported="true" />
        <feature name="component_binding" supported="true" />
        <feature name="component_schema" supported="true" />
        <feature name="screens" supported="true" />
        <feature name="video" supported="true" />
        <feature name="deviceVideo" supported="false" />
        <feature name="accessibility" supported="true" />
        <feature name="dynamic_text_kerning" supported="true" />
        <feature name="static_text_charwidth_nondeviceFont" supported="true" />
        <feature name="static_text_charwidth_deviceFont" supported="true" />
        <feature name="advanced_anti_alias_text" supported="true" />
        <feature name="nine_slice_scaling" supported="true" />
        <feature name="runtimeNumberMinMax" supported="true" />
        <feature name="use8kSampleRate" supported="true" />
        <feature name="useDefineFont4ForDeviceText" supported="true" />
        <feature name="useDefineFont4ForEmbeddedFonts" supported="true" />
        <feature name="textLayoutFramework" supported="true" />
        <encodingPresets>
            <preset uuid="da5cac1a-417a-4d86-b7f7-ef21010a5d7d" name="FLV - Match Source Attributes (High Quality)"
                ext="flv" default="true" />
        </encodingPresets>

        <testmenu>
            <menu name="ID_testInFlash" default="true" />
            <menu name="ID_testInDeviceCentral" />
        </testmenu>

        <debugmenu>
            <menu name="ID_debugtInFlash" default="true" />
            <menu name="ID_debugInDeviceCentral" />
        </debugmenu>

    </player>
</players>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly Just follow the above two answers. For further steps and reference follow the below links,

http://blog.prevail.co.nz/2011/06/21/overlaying-air2-7-in-flash-cs5/comment-page-2/#comment-1803

http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=2949&cpage=1#comment-67603

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add playerglobal.swc FP10.2 for Flash CC on Mac.

Needed this to sort swf version issues with DoubleClick for Advertisers where it doesn't accept versions above 11. Player version and the swf version are no longer in sync.

```
Flash Player 9 = swf version 9
Flash Player 10 and 10.1 = swf version 10
Flash Player 10.2 = swf version 11
Flash Player 10.3 = swf version 12
Flash Player 11 = swf version 13
```

In order to do this for yourself you need to go into "Applications/Adobe Flash CC."

Right click the Flash CC application and select "Show package contents."

Now you need to find the following folder:

/Applications/Adobe Flash CC/Adobe Flash CC.app/Contents/Common/Configuration/Players

You need to duplicate the FlashPlayer10_3.xml as FlashPlayer10_2.xml and replace the relevant details in the file. This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<players>
  <player id="FlashPlayer10.2" version="11" asversion="3">
   <name>Flash Player 10.2</name>
        <path builtin="true" />
        <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
        <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
        <playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.2/playerglobal.swc" />
        <feature name="multiScreenPublish" supported="true" />
        <feature name="mobileAuthoringIntegration" supported="true" />
        <feature name="deviceSound" supported="false" />
        <feature name="exportStreamingSound" supported="true" />
        <feature name="exportEventSound" supported="true" />
        <feature name="FSCommand2" supported="false" />
        <feature name="gradient_linearRGB" supported="true" />
        <feature name="gradient_overflow" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_strokeHint" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_cap" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_join" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_mitre" supported="true" />
        <feature name="shape_scale" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_exportForActionscript" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_exportForRuntimeSharing" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_exportInFirstFrame" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_importForRuntimeSharing" supported="true" />
        <feature name="linkage_importAndAddToCache" supported="false" />
        <feature name="publish_localPlaybackSecurity" supported="true" />
        <feature name="publish_hardwareAcceleration" supported="true" />
        <feature name="symbol_blendMode" supported="true" />
        <feature name="actionScript_documentClass" supported="true" />
        <feature name="symbol_blendMode" supported="true" />
        <feature name="filters" supported="true" />
        <feature name="component_binding" supported="true" />
        <feature name="component_schema" supported="true" />
        <feature name="screens" supported="true" />
        <feature name="video" supported="true" />
        <feature name="deviceVideo" supported="false" />
        <feature name="accessibility" supported="true" />
        <feature name="dynamic_text_kerning" supported="true" />
        <feature name="static_text_charwidth_nondeviceFont" supported="true" />
        <feature name="static_text_charwidth_deviceFont" supported="true" />
        <feature name="advanced_anti_alias_text" supported="true" />
        <feature name="nine_slice_scaling" supported="true" />
        <feature name="runtimeNumberMinMax" supported="true" />
        <feature name="use8kSampleRate" supported="true" />
        <feature name="useDefineFont4ForDeviceText" supported="true" />
        <feature name="useDefineFont4ForEmbeddedFonts" supported="true" />
        <feature name="textLayoutFramework" supported="true" />
        <encodingPresets>
            <preset uuid="da5cac1a-417a-4d86-b7f7-ef21010a5d7d" name="FLV - Match Source Attributes (High Quality)" ext="flv" default="true" />
        </encodingPresets>
        <testmenu>
            <menu name="ID_testInFlash" default="true" />
            <menu name="ID_testInDeviceCentral" />
        </testmenu>
        <debugmenu>
            <menu name="ID_debugtInFlash" default="true" />
            <menu name="ID_debugInDeviceCentral" />
        </debugmenu>
    </player>
</players>
```

The next step is to add your playerglobal.swc to a new folder named FP10.2 here:

/Applications/Adobe Flash CC/Adobe Flash CC.app/Contents/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.2

Make sure you have in fact renamed the swc file to be playerglobal and not playerglobal10_2.

Now if you relaunch Flash you should be good to export at 10.2