# Publishing to Flash 9/10 with Flash Professional CC

Tags: flash, flash-cc

I recently upgraded to Flash Professional CC (Mac 10.8.4) and it no longer gives the option of saving to a version of Flash earlier than 10.3.  But Google DoubleClick and other ad networks only allow versions up to 10.1.  Some even restrict to version 9.

I tried following the directions for CS6 found in this thread [Compile for Flash 10.1 in Flash Professional CS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320405/compile-for-flash-10-1-in-flash-professional-cs6)

But when completed, the Target drop down box in Publish Settings does not list Flash 9 or 10.1.

In short recap, here's what I did:

Create folder path to /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/language/Configuration

Added folders for "ActionScript 3.0" and "Players" (after completed tasks, folders for "ActionsPanel", "Classes", and "Include" were created automatically)

In /ActionScript 3.0 folder, two subfolders ("FP9" and "FP10.1" containing the v9 and v10.1 playerglobal.swc files, respectively)

In /Players folder, inserted two files: "FlashPlayer9_0.xml" and "FlashPlayer10_1.xml".  Here's the code of the v10.1 file, the v9 basically the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<players>
   <player id="FlashPlayer10.1" version="10" asversion="1">
       <name>Flash Player 10.1</name>
       <path builtin="true"/>
       <path menuSortCategory="10"/>
       <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
       <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
       <playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.1/playerglobal.swc" />
       <feature name="multiScreenPublish"               supported="true" />
       <feature name="mobileAuthoringIntegration"           supported="true" />
       <feature name="deviceSound"                  supported="false"/>
       <feature name="exportStreamingSound"         supported="true"/>
       <feature name="exportEventSound"             supported="true"/>
       <feature name="FSCommand2"                   supported="false"/>
       <feature name="gradient_linearRGB"           supported="true" />
       <feature name="gradient_overflow"            supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_strokeHint"             supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_cap"                supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_join"               supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_mitre"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_scale"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_exportForActionscript"    supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_exportForRuntimeSharing"  supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_exportInFirstFrame"       supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_importForRuntimeSharing"  supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_importAndAddToCache"      supported="false" />
       <feature name="publish_localPlaybackSecurity"    supported="true" />
       <feature name="publish_hardwareAcceleration"     supported="true" />
       <feature name="symbol_blendMode"             supported="true" /> 
       <feature name="actionScript_documentClass"       supported="true" />
       <feature name="symbol_blendMode"             supported="true" />
       <feature name="filters"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="component_binding"            supported="true" />
       <feature name="component_schema"             supported="true" />
       <feature name="screens"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="video"                supported="true" />
       <feature name="deviceVideo"              supported="false"/>
       <feature name="accessibility"            supported="true" />
       <feature name="dynamic_text_kerning"         supported="true" />
       <feature name="static_text_charwidth_nondeviceFont"  supported="true" /> 
       <feature name="static_text_charwidth_deviceFont" supported="true" />
       <feature name="advanced_anti_alias_text"         supported="true" /> 
       <feature name="nine_slice_scaling"           supported="true" />
       <feature name="runtimeNumberMinMax"          supported="true" />
       <feature name="use8kSampleRate"                      supported="true" />
       <feature name="useDefineFont4ForDeviceText"          supported="true" />
       <feature name="useDefineFont4ForEmbeddedFonts"       supported="true" />
       <feature name="textLayoutFramework"       supported="true" />
       <feature name="document_class"                   supported="true" />
       <encodingPresets>
            <preset uuid="da5cac1a-417a-4d86-b7f7-ef21010a5d7d"  name="FLV - Match Source Attributes (High Quality)" ext="flv" default="true"/>
        </encodingPresets>

       <testmenu> 
        <menu name="ID_testInFlash" default="true"/>
        <menu name="ID_testInDeviceCentral" />
       </testmenu>

       <debugmenu>
        <menu name="ID_debugtInFlash" default="true"/> 
        <menu name="ID_debugInDeviceCentral"/> 
      </debugmenu>

   </player>
</players>
```

Has anyone been able to get this to work on Flash Professional CC?  I *really* appreciate any help you can give...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, the issue here isn't that the tutorial isn't correct.  The main difference is that Flash CS6 housed those folders in the

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/language/Configuration
```

Folder while CC houses them in the Application Package itself.  So follow the same tutorial but realize that everything is in the

```
/Applications/Adobe Flash CC/Adobe Flash CC.app/Contents/Common/Configuration/
```

Folder instead.  Remember that to enter the Adobe Flash CC.app part you'll just need to right click the app in Finder and select "Show Package Contents" from the context menu.

Here are the directions:

1. Go to http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#playerglobal to download the **Flash Player 10.1** playerglobal.swc file
2. Navigate to your */Applications/Adobe Flash CC/Adobe Flash CC.app/Contents/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0* folder and create a new folder amongst the other FPxx.x folders named "FP10.1" and place your newly downloaded playerglobal.swc file in there. Note: The downloaded file is named playerglobal10_1.swc. Make sure to rename it to just playerglobal.swc.
3. Now head back to the ../Configurations folder (right outside of the ActionScript 3.0 folder) and go into your "Players" folder.  There will be a number of XML files in here.  Find the one named "FlashPlayer10_3.xml", dupilcate it and rename it to "FlashPlayer10_1.xml".
4. You'll need a text editor for this part.  Open the newly duplicated file and change the references to "10.3" to "10.1" (a find/replace should do nicely here), save and you're done.
5. Restart Flash CC and you should have a new option in your export settings for "Flash Player 10.1".

If this doesn't work you may need to add the SWC to your Flash Movie.  You can do that by opening Flash and:

1. Go to File >> ActionScript Settings
2. In the dialog box that pops up, there are three tabs in the middle.  Select the second tab labeled "Library Path"
3. On that tab is a file listing tree that lists, SWC and ANE file locations associated with your Flash Movie or ActionScript file.  Above that directory tree is a toolbar of buttons.  The fourth button (which looks like a polaroid of the Flash Logo) will allow you to navigate to your SWC file to manually link it into your movie.  Select that button, browse to your file and click "Open"
4. Click OK in Actionscript Settings to accept the changes.
5. Save your file, export again.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this blog post and look for kglad's response lower down. It explains exactly what to do to get flash player 9 working in Flash CC.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/5750996

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to show up on the list. You need to copy and paste from the flash 10.3 xml and modify the version info.. also modify the as3 line to point to the 10.1

I think that the code above was for cs6, must've been changed