# Can I get multiple version of Flash Player installed in my system?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, adobe, flash

I have the latest Adobe Flash Player installed in my system. But I am working on a Flash project, which is compatible with only older versions on Flash Player. I don't want to uninstall my current FLash Player.

I need both version 10 and 11 standalone players to try out different Flash projects.

Is it possible to set these up? I couldn't find any satisfactory answers online. My OS is Windows 8.

Thanks!!

Comment: It should be possible to open your .swf files with a stand alone Flash Player Projector of the necessary version. Especially the Debug versions. [See here for Download links](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) And research the topic of Flash Player Projectors and stand alone Debuggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. If you open the swf manually, Windows use the last standalone Flash player used or opened by Windows.
2. If you open the swf with a browser, you can have a multiple portable browsers with different versions of the Flash player, see here: [Enable Flash in Firefox Portable](http://lifehacker.com/394946/enable-flash-in-firefox-portable)
3. If you open the swf inside Flash pro you can set the version of the Flash player you want to use in the swf publish settings, if the flash player you need is not listed en the publish settings you can add it, see here: [Compile for Flash 10.1 in Flash Professional CS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320405/compile-for-flash-10-1-in-flash-professional-cs6).
4. If you are using FlashDevelop or Flash Builder you can set the Flash player version you want to use inside each application.

I hope this helps, best regards

Comment: Hi, I am using FlashDevelop. I have .exe flash players 10 and 11 in my machine. I have set the Flash PLayer version in FlashDevelop in Tools --> Program Settings. But, when I am running the project, it is not opening up! It is trying to connect to it for a long time, and then saying, "[No debug Flash player connection request]". I have set the path to flashplayer_debug.exe, and running the project in Debug mode. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: if flashdevelop is trying to connect for a long time is because the flash player is not debug version. You need to set the standalone debug flash player as default for opening swf files in Windows, open a random swf file in windows explorer to see what is the current default flash player for Windows and to switch versions just open the flashplayer_sa_debug.exe you want to be default

Comment: In FlashDevelop, I pointed to flashplayer_11_ax_debug.exe as the debug flash player. But as I said, it is not opening. When I am double clicking on this exe file, it is saying "installation error as your machine already has the latest flash player (version 14)).

Comment: Sorry, thats not the stand alone flash player, you are trying to run the activex ("ax") flash player for Internet Explorer, the stand alone flash player is flashplayer_11_sa_debug.exe, note the sa letters these are for "stand alone", download it from here [Flash Player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)